# Automapper duplicate formembers

Tags: automapper

Let's say I have the following mappings. Is there a way to reuse the `ForMember` so that I don't have duplicate code?

I have 2 objects (`A, ARequest`) that needs to map to the same object (B)

```cs
 this.CreateMap<A, B>()
.ForMember(dest => dest.test1, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.test1))
.ForMember(dest => dest.test2, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.test2))

 this.CreateMap<ARequest, B>()
.ForMember(dest => dest.test1, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.test1))
.ForMember(dest => dest.test2, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.test2))
```

Comment: I don't think that's possible unless you modify or overwrite the Automapper library.

Comment: Look into Include and IncludeBase. That's the standard way to reuse configuration.

Comment: Ah sure will do..did not know that